# Vuejs - How to render vnodes of child components when using slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How does one render vnodes from a parent component of its child components.
I have a render function that is looping through an array of children found in this.$slots.default. The aim is to wrap the children in li tags.

The problem is that the children components don't render and I get empty li tags. What am I missing here and where can the solution be found in the documentation.
[The Fiddle Can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkbvpop5/2/) And the embedded code is below.

```js
// Parent component
const MyParent = Vue.component('my-parent', {

  render: function(createElement) {
    var parentContent = createElement('h2', "These are Parent's Children:")
    var myChildren = this.$slots.default.map(function(child) {
      //console.log("Child: ", child)

      return createElement(
        'li',
        child
      )
    })

    var content = [].concat(parentContent, myChildren)

    return createElement(
      'div', {},
      content
    )
  }

});


// Child Component
const MyChild = Vue.component('my-child', {
  template: '<h3>I am a child</h3>'
});



// Application Instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyParent,
    MyChild
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-parent>
    <my-child></my-child>
    <my-child></my-child>
  </my-parent>

</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle updated. https://jsfiddle.net/Lkbvpop5/5/

Answer (score 2):

`createElement` takes an array of vnodes. 
It should work like this:

```
return createElement(
   'li',
   [child]) 
})
```